# Instantiating variables from form input JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have this bit of HTML to get some input.  I can validate it, however I don't know how to take in the values and assign them to my own variables.  How can I do this so I can reuse the information?

```
<form name="myForm" target="_top" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName">
Last Name:  <input type="text" name="LastName">
Age:        <input type="text" name="Age"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give an id to each input field you can get the values like this with just plain javascript:

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" target="_top" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
First Name: <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName">
Last Name:  <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName">
Age:        <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var firstname = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
var lastname = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
var age = document.getElementById('Age').value;
alert(firstname+'-'+lastname +'-'+age );
```

If you can use jQuery or Mootools there are other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend adding an ID to *at least* the form itself.

```
<form id="frmMyForm" name="myForm" target="_top" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName">
Last Name:  <input type="text" name="LastName">
Age:        <input type="text" name="Age"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

JavaScript:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('frmMyForm');
var firstName = myForm['FirstName'];
var lastName = myForm['LastName'];
var age = myForm['Age'];
```

---

Best practice would be to add IDs to all input fields that you're going to reference with JavaScript, such as what @Sergio has suggested, but this will work just the same.